# How do I properly pass this Type

Tags: c#, types

I'm looking to do this:

```
Type curType = blah blah...;
dataSet.Add( NewItem<typeof(curType)>() );
```

with NewItem() being:

```
T NewItem<T>(){
  return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

but I cant seem to pass a dynamic type in to NewItem no matter which way I try.

Comment: Look up `MakeGenericMethod` under Reflection.

Comment: What's `dataSet`'s type?

Comment: So you want to dynamically invoke a static wrapper around a dynamic call? You might as well just call `Activator.CreateInstance(curType)` directly.

Comment: @Lee Gah! i'm so dumb, I think I had a problem with that originally then just made it more and more complicated until nothing worked.  Thanks!  make your comment an answer, ill mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance` has an overload which takes a `Type` instance which you are already calling inside the `NewItem` wrapper. You might as well call that directly rather than trying to call `NewItem` dynamically

```
dataSet.Add(curType);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to just have a wrapper for `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`:

```
// using System.Reflection;
Type curType = // blah blah...;
dataSet.Add(GetType().GetMethod("NewItem").MakeGenericMethod(curType).Invoke(this, null));
```

It would probably make more sense to elide the wrapper and instead just call `Activator.CreateInstance` directly by saying `dataSet.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(curType));`.

Comment: @Grundy My code would get more complicated if I added examples of using the asker's classes and other types. I think that it is not too hard to just cast to the appropriate type, and that this cast depends on code that we cannot see here (such as the expected parameter type of `dataSet.Add()`).